# How to construct a branching program for a given function or formula?

Tags: circuits

Can someone throw some light on how to create a branching program from a given function? I have followed the definition of $BP$ on wiki and [here](http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~andrejb/csci5170/notes/16L03.pdf). But I could not find any way to convert a function to $BP$.

P.S: I know $BP$ can be of exponential size for some functions. So any simple function on 3-4 variables will do for example $PARITY$ or $MAJ$.

Comment: This site is for research-level question, which this is not. This would be a fine question for https://cs.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Ok thanks. I thought this is a good question for TCS.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I agree that this is not the right place to ask this question, you might want to look into the following book that contains everything about branching programs that you every wanted to know:

Ingo Wegener: Branching Programs and Binary Decision Diagrams. SIAM 2000, ISBN 0-89871-458-3